# Accessing Excel sheet-specific objects from a self-defined Worksheet object

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a workbook containing one sheet with a checkbox. I am currently accessing that checkbox (named cbFee) using `Sheets("Voltest").cbFee`. This works as intended. However, I want to create a second workbook, so I've saved the first workbook containing my macros and the "Voltest" sheet as an object `wbMacros`. To help cut down on all the typing for `wbMacros.Sheets("Voltest")`, I've shortened it by creating a Worksheet object `wsVoltest` and set it to that worksheet.

However, when I then try to access the checkbox using `wsVoltest.cbFee`, I'm prompted with "Compile error: Method or data member not found."

Here's my code:

Module 1:

```
Public wbMacros As Workbook
Public wbFinish As Workbook
Public wsVoltest As Worksheet

Sub Voltest()
    Set wbMacros = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbFinish = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsVoltest = wbMacros.Sheets("Voltest")

    Application.run "TabNames"
End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Sub TabNames()
Dim voltestSheet As Worksheet
Set voltestSheet = wbMacros.Sheets("Voltest")

' These two message boxes are for testing. They both display the correct value
MsgBox "wbMacros.Sheets: " & wbMacros.Sheets("Voltest").Name
MsgBox "Voltest sheet: " & voltestSheet.Name

' This If works just fine
If wbMacros.Sheets("Voltest").cbFee.Value Then
    MsgBox "If hit"
End If
' This If gives the compile error
If voltestSheet.cbFee.Value Then
    MsgBox "2nd If hit"
End If
```

I'm guessing wsVoltest.Name is working correctly because the Name property is inherent to all Worksheet objects, but checkboxes are not. How do I force the compiler to "know" about the objects that sheet contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the code below, your question can be rephrased to: Why `Debug.Print ws.checkbox1.value` gives an error and how to refer it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Debug.Print Worksheets(1).CheckBox1.Value

    'v----< Error if you uncomment!
    'debug.Print ws.CheckBox1.value

    'v----< This works:
    Debug.Print ws.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value

End Sub
```

The answer is - with `OLEObjects("name").Object`

Comment: Excellent! That worked perfectly. I'm still pretty new to VBA (coming from C#). Now that I have a method name, I can read up on it more.

Comment: @JDCAce - glad I could help. ☺